# NPM Angular Component with TemplateURL?

Tags: angular, npm, ionic2

I am trying to package an Angular component that has a template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  templateUrl: 'foo.component.html'
})
export class FooComponent {

}
```

In the same folder is my template

```
<div>Foo Component</div>
```

I want to package this and distribute to npm so I can install it in another project.

```
npm install foo
```

And add it to my other project

```
import {FooComponent} from 'foo';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FooComponent
  ]
})
```

So I can add it to my project via the selector

```
<div>
  Foo Component: <foo></foo>
</div>
```

But I'm not sure how to build this and export so the template can be resolved. My template is pretty large so I don't want an inline template. How would I do this?

Comment: Sorry If I don't get your question clearly, normally, you put your template with your component.ts in the same folder.

Comment: I dont understand your question clearly. So, what is your main purpose?

Comment: I've updated my original question. Hopefully that makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Your templateUrl should be, if it's in current directory

```
templateUrl: './foo.component.html'
```

Use `./` for current directory.